# Помогите найти аналог этого шрифта с кириллицей

Tags: css, шрифты, web-fonts

Сильно понравился мне этот шрифт, и только я хотел использовать его на сайте, как понял - нету кириллицы. Можете подсказать похожий шрифт с кириллицей, и чтобы бесплатный был?

[Hero Light](https://nomail.com.ua/family/Hero%20Light)

Comment: Могу предлагать этот шрифт https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Comfortaa?query=comfortaa&preview.text=Привет&preview.text_type=custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, нашел на другом сайте, версию с кириллицей. Не знаю почему на моём нету. Но вот ссылка

[Hero 2](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/hero-2)

Answer (score 1):

могу посоветовать [Neometric Extra Light](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/neometric-2)

Comment: Неплохо, если использовать тонкое начертание, но всё ещё слишком угловатое, а мне нужны круглые концы на символах

Answer (score 1):

С первого взгляда в голову пришла [Comfortaa](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Comfortaa?query=comfortaa&preview.text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&preview.text_type=custom)